# Ordered Array Initialization Syntax in C

Tags: c, arrays

I came across an unfamiliar array initialization syntax in the code of [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/xv6.html).
Original code is in syscall.s

```
static int (*syscalls[])(void) = {
[SYS_fork]    sys_fork,
[SYS_exit]    sys_exit,
[SYS_wait]    sys_wait,
// ...
[SYS_halt]  sys_halt,
};
```

I ran my sample code to confirm this

```
const char* mystrings[] = {
   [2] "this",
   [1] "is",
   [0] "cool",
};


int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
   printf("%s %s %s\n",mystrings[0],mystrings[1],mystrings[2]);

        return 0;
}
```

Output was

```
cool is this
```

What is this kind of array initialization in C code? Where can i ( find documentation for this? ( I compiled with gcc 4.6.3 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Designated initializers*, part of C99. See for example [the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). The current standard reference is C11 6.7.9.

However, GCC offers a few extensions to this syntax, such as omitting the `=` sign, or ranges.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Well spotted, thanks a lot! I incorporated that in the post.